# MVC DisplayFormat for DateTime not giving the right value to textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, formatting, datetimepicker

I'm trying to set a default date and time value for my date picker in MVC. To accomplish this, the value of the textbox element with type="DateTime-local" should be: 
    **'2017-12-14T08:30'**
(As is noted here https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#element-statedef-input-localdatetime). I tried all sorts of different date format strings, but I can't seem to find the correct one.

```
[DisplayName("New time")]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss}",ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime NewTime { get; set; }
```

This results in me getting a normal DateTime formatting:

[Current DateTime formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x30sC.png)

Code for rendering the input:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewTime)
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "datetime-local" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewTime)
            </div>
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: How do you render the input?

Comment: @Zabavsky Ah sorry, forgot, i updated my question with the razor code responsible for rendering the input.

Comment: I just tried your code and the `value` attribute is in correct format for me `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`. There might be some global editor template for DateTime that overrides it. Also note, the date in the `value` attribute and the date you actually see in the input most likely will have different formats.

Comment: Have a look if browser console is giving any complaints, also which browser?